# Get repeating content by regex

Tags: python, regex, multiline, multilinestring

I have some content in the format:

```
text = """Pos no
...
... 25/gm
The Text to be 
...
excluded
Pos no
...
... 46 kg
The Text to be 
...
excluded
Pos no
...
... 46 xunit
End of My Text
```

Where,
`Pos no... 25/gm` - It is a sort of tabular structure from which I have to extract the values.

`The Text to be ... excluded` - This has constant start (lets say `The Text to be`) but not definite end i.e `excluded`  might not be present.

`End of My Text` -
This text will always be present.

I want a list with the tabular content only i.e.

```
["Pos no
...
... 25/gm",
"Pos no
...
... 46 kg",
"Pos no
...
... 46 xunit"]
```

Here is my try but its not fetching the right list:

```
re.findall(r'(Pos no .+?)(?: |The Text to be|End of My Text)', text, re.DOTALL | re.M)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
re.findall(r'(?sm)(Pos no\r?\n.+?)[\r\n]+(?:The Text to be|End of My Text)', text)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/kgmTG9)

Note that `Pos no` has no space, but your pattern required it. Also, matching the right-hand context only when it is at the start of a line will make matching safer.

**Pattern details**

- `(?sm)` - `re.DOTALL` and `re.MULTILINE` inline modifiers (for shorter code)
- `(Pos no\r?\n.+?)` - Group 1 (what is returned by `re.findall`):

  - `Pos no` - a literal substring
  - `\r?\n` - a CRLF or LF line break
  - `.+?` - any 1+ chars, as few as possible up to the leftmost occurrence of the subsequent subpatterns
- `[\r\n]+` - 1+ line break chars
- `(?:The Text to be|End of My Text)` - either of the two substrings, `The Text to be` or  `End of My Text`.

Comment: [Another demo with the same approach](https://ideone.com/d8X9DS), just different printing of the results.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. But looks like somehow its not working with actual client data. One guess I have done is, actual data contains `utf-8` characters, so wondering does it make any difference when text has `utf-8` characters in it.

Comment: @Laxmikant Do you mean there are Unicode line breaks? Replace `[\r\n]` with `[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029]` and `\r?\n` with `\u000D\u000A|[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029]`. Also, are `Pos no`, `The Text to be` and `End of My Text` on separate fiull lines? Add `\s*` to allow leading or trailing whitespaces. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IEP3kC/1).